# ControlValueAccessor not updating value in form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i have written a compoent to wrap a wysiwyg javascript plugin
i have implemented ControlValueAccesor and binded it to ngModel in my form
but the value of the field is always underfined
even if the inner _value of the component that wrap the wyiwug is correct
here is the code.

changing `content` value in parent do change the content of the child form control component.

**trumobowyg.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors,
  NG_VALIDATORS
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'trumbowyg',
  templateUrl: './trumbowyg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trumbowyg.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrumbowygComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrumbowygComponent),
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})

export class TrumbowygComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator{

  private _content: string;
  private _elm: any;

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
  propagateTouch = () => {};

  constructor(private elmRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let self = this;

    this._elm = (<any> $('div', this.elmRef.nativeElement)).trumbowyg();

    this._elm
      .on('tbwfocus', function() {
        self.propagateTouch();
      })

      .on('tbwchange', function() {
        self.content = self._elm.trumbowyg('html');
      })
  }


  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
  set content(v: any) {
    if (v !== this._content) {
      this._content = v;
      this.propagateChange(v);
    }
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if(obj !== undefined) {
      this._content = obj;
      this._elm.trumbowyg('html', this._content);
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }


  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|any {
    ( this._content && this._content.length > 0 ) ? null : {
      valid: false,
    }
  }

}
```

**form**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCommentSubmit()">
  <ng-container  *ngIf="(user | async)" class="">

    <trumbowyg [(ngModel)]="content"  name="content"></trumbowyg>

    <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse pt-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid"> Valider </button>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like content setter never be invoked (therefore `propagateChange` too) due to the fact that value pass through `writeValue(obj:any)` method where you assign new value directly to `_content`